# How do I force Weblogic 10.3.6 to use my pre-compiled JSP classes?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am pre-compiling hundreds of JSP files in a legacy project with a Maven plugin at compile/package time to validate that the JSP files are correct.

I want to be able to use the `.class` files that JSP compiler produces and places in `WEB-INF/classes` instead of Weblogic recompiling the JSP again when the `.ear` is deployed.

I have been unsuccessful in finding this information on how to accomplish this in Oracle's documentation.

#### What is the magic incantation to tell Weblogic 10.3.6 ( 11g ) not to try and compile any of the JSPs and just look on the classpath for the `.class` files?

Comment: I think I got it. Do you want to deploy the war file containing jsp files, but you want your jsp files ignored, and instead, wl to look them up in the classpath?

Comment: Sounds like you may have already tried it but just in case... what about setting both `page-check-seconds` and `precompile` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1038491 in combination with Weblogic appc for precompilatiom? https://blogs.oracle.com/groundside/entry/jsp_precompilation_for_adf_applications